# Почему не видны иконки с SVG спрайта в FireFox?

Tags: reactjs, svg

Добавляю иконки в верстку при помощи SVG спрайтов, иконка отображается в Opera, Chrome, но не отображается в FireFox

Скриншот с FireFox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот с Chrome:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код с помощью которого я добавляю иконку:

```js
import React from 'react';

import './LeftNav.css';

class LeftNav extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <aside className='left-aside'>
                <a href='#' className='left-aside__logo'>
                    <img src='img/logo.png' alt='logotype' />
                </a>
                <nav className='left-aside__naviagtion'>
                    <a href='#' className='left-aside__link'>
                        <svg className='left-aside__icon'>
                            <use xlinkHref='img/icons/icon-sprite.svg#search' />
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </nav>
                
            </aside>
        )
    }
}

export default LeftNav;
```

Возможно это связано с React.js т.к. в других моих проектах, все хорошо работает, но там я не использую React.

Comment: Консоль ни на что не ругается?

Comment: @RogatnevNikita, не-а, в консоли только про атрибут href говориться. Я попробовал еще добавить чисто в index.html эту иконку, тоже не работает

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, можешь залить мин. пример на CodeSandbox?

Comment: @Arthur, постараюсь

Comment: @Arthur, видимо какая-то проблема с путями была или с названием файла SVG спрайта, либо вообще с иконками, достал файл с другого проекта, все отлично заработало

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, у меня такая же проблема была, когда копировал эти же файлы и вставлял в другой проект, весьма непонятная ошибка на первый взгляд

Comment: @Arthur, Главное то, что такие ошибки не реально пофиксить практически. Я вот начал заливать все это дело на sandbox и обнаружил, что там все окей, хотя я не левый файл подключал, а напрямую добавил SVG спрайт в index.html, но все равно использовал use, и все работало, правда, вставляло сразу 3 иконки вместо одной :) Это вообще странно

Answer (score 1):

`Firefox` - наиболее правильно обрабатывает `svg` Если в нем не отражается, значит, что-то неправильно написано в `SVG`
`Chrome` часто использует экспериментальные технологии, с помощью которых проглатываются ошибки. Но это ловушка, где-нибудь потом всё равно вылезает ошибка.

Попробуйте заменить вызов иконки:

```
<use xlinkHref='img/icons/icon-sprite.svg#search' />
```

на

`<use xlink:href='img/icons/icon-sprite.svg#search' />`

А лучше всегда добавлять в вопрос код иконки, как правило там обнаруживается проблема.